# Why does alah[j+1] here doesn't do anything?

Tags: c++

So i have a simple little code here that tries to input `n` and then makes an array with size `n-1` that is formatted like this:

Example of `n = 7`

```
1  0  0  0  0  0   <- The first line is always like this
1  2  1  0  0  0
0  1  2  1  0  0
0  0  1  2  1  0
0  0  0  1  2  1
0  0  0  1 -2  1  <- The last line is always like this
```

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n,i,j;
    cout<<"input jumlah partisi : "; cin>>n; cout<<endl;

    int alah [n-1] [n-1];

    for(i=0;i<=n-2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=n-2;j++){
            alah[i][j]=0;
            if(i==j){
                alah[i][j+1]=1; // <<<<<< Here is the problem
                alah[i][j]=2;
                alah[i][j-1]=1;
            }

            //Last line
            if(i==n-2){
                if(i==j){
                    alah[i][j]=1;
                    alah[i][j-1]=-2;
                    alah[i][j-2]=1;
                }
            }

            //First line
            if(i==0){
                if(i==j){
                    alah[i][j]=1;
                }
            }

        }

    }

    for (i=0;i<=n-2;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=n-2;j++){
            cout<<alah[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Instead it outputs this (I've tried this Windows, Linux, and Ideone):

```
1  0  0  0  0  0
1  2  0  0  0  0
0  1  2  0  0  0
0  0  1  2  0  0
0  0  0  1  2  0
0  0  0  1 -2  1
```

What happens here? Additional note : if I change alah[i][j+1] with alah[i][j-n+1], it will makes an almost perfect code and I know it was because it fills the previous line instead of the current line. By the way, about the ineffeciency of the code, I've made something more efficient but I want to know why this particular code doesn't work. Thank you.

Comment: I encourage you to learn how to use a debugger

Comment: Never use `using namespace std;`. Instead use `using std::cout;` etc. for each *individual* object that you want ... or even just qualify them when you use them.

Comment: Why is the field size n-1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your bug is that all your work is being undone by the next loop iteration:

```
alah[i][j]=0;
```

I would've initialized the whole array to 0 first, thus avoided the problem.